# (Node Express)Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, express

Refused to apply style because of MIME type. I can't serve css for my html page via Express. I've tried everything but I feel like I am overlooking something simple and just would like some fresh eyes to analyze my code to see where I am messing up at.

> server.js

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));

 app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
 })
```

The index.html runs just fine but without any css styling.

My html css link is:

> link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"

and my file structure is

```
                     >backend
                      index.html
                      server.js

                     >public
                       styles.css
```

Comment: what is the content that is actually returned for `styles.css`

Comment: the error i recieve is Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. When I open dev tools my css is served as a 404 page which is the issue I'm stuck at.

Comment: You already said what the error was. Anyway, as it's a 404 page, the path is wrong somehow - other than the file structure being not what you actually show, can't see an issue

Comment: Syntactically speaking though the code looks correct though ? It's probably a configuration issue I'll keep hacking away at it and see if I overlooked something super simple. Thank you for your input! Btw the file structure I provided is exactly as it is in my vsCode thats why I'm so stuck because in other answers regarding the topics I saw people mess up their file structure or make a small typo and didn't notice but I quadruple checked to ensure I didn't make a simple mistake like that. Something tells me I am overlooking another simple issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `/public` does not have a forward slash at the end, you can try it including in `href` your HTML.

```
link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css"
```

Also, check your static `public` folder is actually set up correctly with provided path and that can access your `styles.css` file.

Comment: Thank you for your input ! The solution that worked for me was changing my file structure by moving my index.html into my public folder so that the css and html share the same directory as well as move the server.js file outside and removing the backend folder completely. I appreciate the help. Now that I have it working I must ask if what I did is considered good practice or not ?          >public now contains only styles.css and index.html

Comment: If you put your `index.hrml` into a static shared folder, probably you can access it directly. No need to serve it by root endpoint. The best way is separate the file structure.